# Java + Selenium: ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am on EBays' advance uploader tool (URL: http://cgi5.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?NewListing&cpg=20&aid=1&from=wn&sid=529765574701&itemid=0&cat1=177005 ). I click on yellow box "click to add photos - first photo required" - I am able to upload the first photo using the XPath  `".//*[@id='upl-fileInp']";` However when I try uploading the second or third photo using XPath `".//input[contains(@class,'upl-fileInp')]"` I get element not visible exception in Selenium. I understand the origin of the error but I don't see the element not beingvisible. I have tried many different variations of XPath and to no avail. I've tried webdriver wait and did not work either. The HTML code is:

```
<li kp="1" data="">
<span class="tg-li">
<div class="thumb" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<div class="disableLyr" style="display: none;"/>
<a class="del" title="delete"/>
<div class="guide">
<div class="throb">
<a class="addPicBtn" style="display: block;">
<i/>
<b>Add photos</b>
<input id="upl-11450764546022" class="upl-fileInp" type="file" multiple="" title="Select photos" value="" name="d"/>
</a>
<div class="picIcon" style="display: none;"/>
<a class="genericError" tabindex="0" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</span>
</li>
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li kp="1" data="">
<li class="last" kp="1" data="">
</ul>
<div id="tg-mainPicPnl" tabindex="-1">Main photo</div>
</div>
<div class="arrow rt">
</div>
<!-- TODO: Remove. Replaced by BubbleText. ******************************************* Thumbnails gallery tooltip *********************************************** <div id="tg-tooltip"><div class="ptr"></div><div class="msg"><div class="pad"><span class="hdg"></span><b>:</b><span class="bdy"></span><div class="hide"></div></div></div></div>-->
<!--******************************************* BubbleText ***********************************************-->
<div id="bt-bubbleTextTmp" class="puBubbleText">
<div id="up-uploadBtnWrap" style="display: inline-block;">
</form>
</div>
<!--
```

Comment: can you share your test code?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a very good option, but try to use `sleep` and that way you will know if your problem is in waiting or not. For example

```
sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using explicit wait would be more appropriate, try waiting for the specific element before trying to click it. like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'upl-fileInp')]")));

element.click();
```